# CodeIgniter - Insert selected value to database from a dropdown

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to add remarks such as "good", "very good", and "improving" to the `rem1` column in the database.
Whichever remark is chosen in the dropdown list should be saved in the table.
However, I get a null value when I execute the code below.
What am I doing wrong?

This is my view code:

```
<div>
  <select class="form-control" name="remark">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose option</option>
    <option name="exam_group_student_remark_<?php echo $student['exam_group_class_batch_exam_students_id']; ?>" value="Good">Good</option>
    <option name="exam_group_student_remark_<?php echo $student['exam_group_class_batch_exam_students_id']; ?>" value="Very Good">Very Good</option>
    <option name="exam_group_student_remark_<?php echo $student['exam_group_class_batch_exam_students_id']; ?>" value="Improving">Improving</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
 if (!empty($exam_group_student_id)) {
 foreach ($exam_group_student_id as $exam_group_student_key => $exam_group_student_value) {


 $array = array(
 'exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id' => $this->input->post('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'),
 'exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id' => $exam_group_student_value,
 'rem1' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_remark_' . $exam_group_student_value),
 
 );
 $insert_array[] = $array;
 }
 }
 $this->examgroupstudent_model->add_result($insert_array);
```

Comment: I think input values are resolved by name, so try `$this->input->post('remark')` instead.

Comment: This dropdown appears against each student's name to be selected. I just noticed that only the last student's remark get recorded for all the students.

Comment: Well all the inputs probably have the same name, so you only really get one value. You could add the students id as identifier.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Well I would have to see your full code and stuff, but let's say that's for you to figure out :)

Comment: When you don't know what is in the submission payload, just print the whole payload out.  `var_export($this->input->post());`.  Name attributes in option tags are worthless/meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Use code like this,in php take name attribute in 'select' tag not in 'option' tag

```
<div>
  <select class="form-control" name="remark">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose option</option>
    <option value="Good">Good</option>
    <option value="Very Good">Very Good</option>
    <option value="Improving">Improving</option>
  </select>
</div>
//controller

if (!empty($exam_group_student_id)) {
 foreach ($exam_group_student_id as $exam_group_student_key => $exam_group_student_value) {


 $array = array(
 'exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id' => $this->input->post('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'),
 'exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id' => $exam_group_student_value,
 'rem1' => $this->input->post('remark'),
 
 );
 $insert_array[] = $array;
 }
 }
 $this->examgroupstudent_model->add_result($insert_array);
```

Comment: It is never necessary to declare the `value` attribute of an option tag if it is identical to the option's text value.